# SQL select query into delete statement

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select acc.Username from accounts acc
left join accountevents ace on acc.accountid=ace.accountid
left join leads lds on lds.leadid=acc.leadid
where lds.DateEntered>'2011-01-01' and lds.DateEntered<'2011-02-01'
Group by acc.Username
Having count(ace.accounteventid)=0
```

I wanted to make it a delete statement:

```
delete username from accounts 
left join accountevents ace on accounts.accountid=ace.accountid 
left join leads lds on lds.leadid=accounts.leadid
where Leads.DateEntered>'2011-01-01' and lds.DateEntered<'2011-02-01' 
Having count(accountevents.accounteventid)=0
```

And i get the following error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Having'.

Any suggestions?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: You took the GROUP BY clause off in the delete - you need a GROUP BY to use a HAVING, otherwise just use `AND COUNT(Blah) = 0`, count doesn't **require** a GROUP BY

Answer (score 5):

I think you should re-write it the following way:

```
delete from accounts where username in ( <here goes your select statement> );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the select query it is obvious that the table accounts have a relationship with the table accountevents and leads.  So first you have to delete the record from the child table or Foreign key table and the from the primary table.
Run this query if you have set the `DELETE Rule to CASCADE` in the database design or your table.

```
DELETE FROM [TableName] where UserName ='UserName'   -- TableName should be your primary table it may be Accounts or AccountsEvents or Leads
```

and If you have not set the DELETE Rule in the Database design then you have to run three queries. First delete the data from the child table and then from the parent.

```
Delete from accounts where username = 'name'
Delete from eventsaccounts where accountid = 'accountsid'
Delete from leads where leadid = 'leadid'
```